# Reload tableview data duplicate

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

i'm using an NSTimer on the label text inside the uitableviewcell. This label text is updated every 5 seconds and every 5 seconds i call [reload theTableView]; Instead of updating it seem to duplicate instead of overwriting how come is that:

Here is a image when the data is reloaded:

[image]

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{



chatCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
if (cell == nil) cell = [[chatCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;




cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:243/255.0f green:243/255.0f blue:247/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
    cell.homeTeamLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(80, 10, 140, 20)];
    cell.homeTeamLabel.text = [[arrayBarclay objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"hometeam" ];
    cell.homeTeamLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0];
    cell.homeTeamLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:cell.homeTeamLabel];

    cell.awayTeamLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(80, 30, 140, 20)];
    cell.awayTeamLabel.text = [[arrayBarclay objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"awayteam" ];
    cell.awayTeamLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0];
    cell.awayTeamLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:cell.awayTeamLabel];


    cell.homeTeamScore = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(cell.frame.size.width-50, 10, 30, 20)];
    cell.homeTeamScore.text = [[arrayBarclay objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"homescore" ];
    cell.homeTeamScore.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0];
    cell.homeTeamScore.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:cell.homeTeamScore];

    cell.awayTeamScore = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(cell.frame.size.width-50, 30, 30, 20)];
    cell.awayTeamScore.text = [[arrayBarclay objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"awayscore" ];
    cell.awayTeamScore.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0];
    cell.awayTeamScore.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:cell.awayTeamScore];


    cell.time = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0, 40, 60)];
    cell.time.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    cell.time.text = [[arrayBarclay objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"time" ];
    cell.time.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0];
    cell.time.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:cell.time];

}
```

Comment: i think in your cellForRow at IndexPath you are creating a new label and adding it as subView to cell.thats the reason, as the cell is being reused you are adding it again and again.

Comment: Thats correct, since i'm not using storyboard, what would be the fix for this?

Comment: Please post your code for `-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` - I presume you're using this to populate rows

Comment: when you create a label initially, set it a tag value and then add it as subView. Now every time when cellForIndexPath is called, check whether any subView with that tag value is there or not. If its not there ,create label else just change its content.

Comment: possible duplicate of [UITableview items becomes bold after scrolling up](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21472602/uitableview-items-becomes-bold-after-scrolling-up)

Comment: Please show your code in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: hey CaptJak. i've added the method now. I have several subviews in it. How can i fix so it does not add the subviews on top of each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
     chatCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
     if (cell == nil){
        cell = [[chatCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];

        //It's better to move following code to chatCell
        //And ChatCell className will also be better.
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:243/255.0f green:243/255.0f blue:247/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
        cell.homeTeamLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(80, 10, 140, 20)];
        cell.homeTeamLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0];
        cell.homeTeamLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:cell.homeTeamLabel];

        cell.awayTeamLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(80, 30, 140, 20)];
        cell.awayTeamLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0];
        cell.awayTeamLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:cell.awayTeamLabel];

        cell.homeTeamScore = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(cell.frame.size.width-50, 10, 30, 20)];

        cell.homeTeamScore.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0];
        cell.homeTeamScore.textColor = [UIColor blackColor]
        [cell.contentView addSubview:cell.homeTeamScore];

        cell.awayTeamScore = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(cell.frame.size.width-50, 30, 30, 20)];
        cell.awayTeamScore.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0];
        cell.awayTeamScore.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:cell.awayTeamScore];

        cell.time = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0, 40, 60)];
        cell.time.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        cell.time.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0];
        cell.time.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:cell.time];
     }  

     //Move [arrayBarclay objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] out  will be better.
     NSDictionnary *contentDict = [arrayBarclay objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
     cell.homeTeamLabel.text = [contentDict objectForKey:@"hometeam"];
     cell.awayTeamLabel.text = [contentDict objectForKey:@"awayteam"];
     cell.homeTeamScore.text = [contentDict objectForKey:@"homescore" ];
     cell.awayTeamScore.text = [contentDict objectForKey:@"awayscore" ];
     cell.time.text = [contentDict objectForKey:@"time" ];

     return cell;
}
```

If you want to reuse a cell, you'd better init its subviews in its init method. `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` will be called any time cell will be displayed. If you need `addsubview` dynamically， remove previous added views first.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use `[cell addSubview:yourView];` in cellForRowAtIndexPath, it will keep adding subviews on your cell regardless if it is there or not already. Subclass UITableViewCell and alloc all your views and add them in the initialization, then reference those properties and update them how you'd like in the method called by your NSTimer.